# Getting child data in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have been banging my head against this all night.

I have a service that is returning data that looks like this:
[image]

You will see there are Objects with a GUID, nested under a parent object.   I need to loop through all the "GUID" objects and get the attributes (i.e., author, content, etc.).

The GUIDs are dynamic (I don't know what they are ahead of time).  The attributes below it are known.

I am having trouble figuring out how to target it.  I can't seem to successfully use a `for` or `forEach` loop on it.

I need to use native JavaScript (i.e. no jQuery for this one).

Comment: Easy way to use nested `for` according nested level , `for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)` !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
var results = 
keys.map(
  function(key){
      var datum = data[key];
      // do whatever with the data.
      return {
        "author" : data["author"]
      }
  }
)
// now results is an array of {"author"} objects.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var x = {
  'a-45-2455': {
    'author': 'Some Name'
  }
};
    var keys = Object.keys(x);
    keys.forEach(function(key,value){
       var author = x[key]['author'];
       console.log(author);
    });
```

You can access the data in this way. 
You can also create another array from the values and use that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to loop through an object use [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Since you have not posted the code of object , here is a snippet with dummy object

```js
var x = {
  'a-45-2455': {
    'author': 'Some Name'
  }
}
   for(var keys in x){
    alert(x[keys].author)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular try angular.forEach loop to iterate over all GUID's, else you can use for each in javascript. see below code snippet.

```js
var user ={
  '1': {
  "name":'abc',
  "age":26
  },
  '2': {
  "name":'def',
  "age":28
  }
};

for(var key in user) {
  console.log(user[key].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can iterate through all indexes using the advanced for loop. `a.b` is the same as `a["b"]` in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to iterate through json Object

```
 var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {a: 1, b: 2}};
 function walk(obj) {
 for (var key in obj) {
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  var val = obj[key];
  console.log(val);

         walk(val);
         }
      }
    }
 walk(obj);
```

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {a: 1, b: 2}};
function walk(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var val = obj[key];
      console.log(val);
      
      walk(val);
    }
  }
}
walk(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate thru the object properties like this:

```
for(let key in Response){
  if(!Response.hasOwnProperty(key))
    continue;
  //key will be each GUID
  let yourObject = Response[key] //Each object in the list of objects
}
```

You can read about [for...in loops here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Hope that helps!